# Migrating HDD's from one File System to another

Tags: hard-drive, backup, hfs, exfat

I have been using Mac for many years and I have just recently switched to a Windows 10 based workstation.

I have 14 HDDs (with physical backup drives =28 drives) which were all formatted in OSX journaled extended and contain my library of work.

Now that I am on PC, I would like to be able to use them on the PC as well as Mac going forward.

What I know so far is that exFat is the file system I should be using going forward, and with this knowledge, I purchased a 4tb drive to use as an exFat 'mule' to copy the data to, then reformat my source drive to exFat and dump the original data back onto the source drive.

FYI; On the mac, I have a Thunderbolt 2 dual bay HDD 'toaster' and on the PC I have a dual bay USB 3.1gen2 (10gb) toaster) as I use HDD's to physically work between machines, versions and backup's etc.

Apart from the 'phantom' 500gb that finder tells me is now present on the mule drive (it states that there is 3.17tb of used space on it, where the source drive only had 2.76tb of data...), the workload of having to do this workflow; transfer>check for inconsistencies>ok>reformat original source drive>dump data back on to original source drive>verify and repeat is going to be a heinous workload and without checksum verification is going to take me forever.

Is there a simpler way to do a checksum verifiable, back up between an (HFS) source drive an (exFat) mule drive on exFat different file systems?

I own a copy of Carbon Copy Cloner, but I cant see that this is an option, and there is nothing I can find on their support pages.

Is there anything at all out there that I'm unaware of that might help make this process easier for me?

Comment: ExFAT does not offer the protections included with NTFS or JHFS+. There is a very good chance your data will become corrupted at some point.

Comment: Thank. I don't have a choice if I want my drives to be accessible between two platforms.

Comment: Buy a cheap mac mini or something, mount the drives as they are now and share the files over the network.